# Elliptic surfaces with monodromy in Borel subgroup

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Are there restrictions on the invariants of an elliptic surface $M\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} C$ for the monodromy of its homological invariant to be contained in the upper triangular subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

In particular, do you know example of minimal properly elliptic surfaces with $a(M)=1$ and the above property?

Thanks for reading

Comment: The invariants under the monodromy in $H^1$ of a (geometric) generic fiber equals the image of pullback of $H^1$ of the surface.  Since the Hodge structure of an elliptic curve is irreducible, this means pullback is surjective (if the invariants are nonzero).  This implies the family is isotrivial.